# Is there a CocoaPods Library for Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

I downloaded an open source project via Cocoapods that I am modifying and I'm trying to add the Parse Framework but it seems I can not access the framework within the open source file located in the Pods Directory. I have included the Parse framework in my own project directory where I can access the Parse framework within files located in my project directory but there's an error when I try to access it within the open source file...so I was wondering if there was a Cocoapods version of Parse.

I typed in Parse in the Cocoapods Search Website but I can only find ParseUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't see it listed, but just do:

`pod 'Parse'`

Comment: Wow...aha...and to think i  was stuck on this for some time. Thanks totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pod 'Parse-iOS-SDK', '~&gt; 1.3'
```

in your Podfile

Comment: I would not use this one, is it not the official one and is also out of date. It seems to use v1.2.18 of the Parse iOS SDK, the most recent version is 1.7.5, use the official one instead